# Print SSRS Report Automatically

Tags: reporting-services, printing, reportingservices-2005, business-intelligence

I am fairly new to using SSRS and I would like to create a report that automatically prints to a specified printer when the report is generated.

I found this question on SO and it mentions writing code in the Business Intelligence Development Studio that can "fire off" a print job.  How might I do that?

EDIT:

Forgot the URL of the thread in question.
[Automatically print SSRS report?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480723/automatically-print-ssrs-report)

Comment: A quick google reveals many hits on "Print SSRS Report" using vb.net or c# etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As TFD commented google will get you lots of responses.

From my experience there are 2 ways to "automatically" print a report.

- If it will be on demand from your code then you will have to code the rendering and send that to the printer yourself. There are lots of ways/variations to do this, again google will give you more specifics.
- You can also write a custom extension to do the printing. There are samples of this in the SSRS sample code as part of the SSRS server install. This would do the printing "server side".