# Print a report generated by Microsoft's Report Viewer

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I have used to Microsoft Report wizard to create a Report (a delivery receipt) for a Transport application. Now I want the end user to be able to print the receipt as soon as he clicks a button. The problem is that on click of a button the report is first loaded and then he has to select the print button. I want to automate the process of loading and printing. The guy has to print about 200-300 receipts a day and it is very time consuming to follow the current method!

I am developing using C# and working on Microsoft visual studio 2010. I am working on winForms desktop application and the report is local

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Automatically print SSRS report?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480723/automatically-print-ssrs-report)

Comment: I am working on a desktop application. I cannot add the Web reference

Comment: Please specify what report type and database you are connecting to, as many people think it is a SSRS report on SQL Server.

Comment: The report is local and not on a report server. It is generated using data from a DataSet.xsd. I am using reportviewer to view the report inside a form!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252091.aspx

It generates a file and prints that to the default printer. I have used this a derivative of this before, and it worked OK (if I remember correctly) but I had to add some code to clear down the EMF file once printed.

Seems like a lot of code to do something so simple, but it may help?

Comment: @CYMR0: I tried the same thing but i seem to get a error message!

Comment: @CYMR0: In that code, cant i just give in the report and remove the DataTable LoadSalesData() function and report.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("Sales", LoadSalesData())); line in the Run function?

Comment: Error is on line: report.Render("Image", deviceInfo, CreateStream, out warnings);

Comment: The report is bringing in data from a sales table. You can get rid of it I think, but you would need to bring in data some other way. What error message are you getting on that line??

Comment: @CYMR0: Thanks a ton mate! It worked like a gem! Just one more thing, while deployment should this report be copied to output directory (because i need to specific the file path in the code)?

Comment: @saurabh - glad I could help. Don't know what you mean about the deployment - if you're deploying as a clickonce application or just distributing the exe that should be enough - although you'll need to make sure they have the reportviewer installed (which clickonce does I think).

Answer (score -2):

If you are using crystal report, you could use `ReportDocument.PrintToPrinter` method. Have a look at [this](http://csharp.net-informations.com/crystal-reports/csharp-crystal-reports-print.htm).

Comment: the OP refers to SSRS, not CR.

Comment: I am using visual studio's inbuilt reporting feature!